# regex Python: "pull-out" entire group but keep everything else in String

Tags: regex

Assume we can have incoming strings in the following forms:

```
st = 'Skank Up [feat. Ding Dong] (Oh Lawd)'
st2 = 'Skank Up (Oh Lawd) [feat. Ding Dong]'
st3 = 'Skank Up (Oh Lawd) (feat. Ding Dong)'
```

In all three cases, I want to end up with:

```
'Skank Up (Oh Lawd)'
```

How can this be done with regex?

Farthest I've come is:

```
st = re.match('.*(?:\(feat|\[feat)', st)
```

But this returns:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 14), match='Skank Up [feat'>
```

Comment: Try [`re.sub(r'\s*(?:\[feat[^][]+]|\(feat[^()]+\))|[()]', '', st)`](https://regex101.com/r/z79JxM/1).

Comment: This removes the parenthesis around "(Oh Lawd)" unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, `re.sub(r'\s*(?:\[feat[^][]+]|\(feat[^()]+\))', '', st)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/z79JxM/2)), the `|[()]` is redundant.

Comment: Perfect. Can you add as an answer so I can accept? (an explanation would be super, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove the brackets that start with `feat` using `re.sub` like

```
re.sub(r'\s*(?:\[feat[^][]+]|\(feat[^()]+\))', '', st)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z79JxM/2)

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\[feat[^][]+]|\(feat[^()]+\))` - a non-capturing group matching two alternatives:

  - `\[feat[^][]+]` - `[`, then `feat`, then 1+ chars other than `]` and `[` and then `]`
  - `|` - or
  - `\(feat[^()]+\)` - `(`, then `feat`, then 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`.

You may also use a slight variation if there is nothing but `feat` inside brackets:

```
re.sub(r'\s*(?:\[feat[^]]*]|\(feat[^)]*\))', '', st)
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/2MrSxt):

```
import re
sts = ['Skank Up [feat. Ding Dong] (Oh Lawd)','Skank Up (Oh Lawd) [feat. Ding Dong]', 'Skank Up (Oh Lawd) (feat. Ding Dong)']
for st in sts:
    print(re.sub(r'\s*(?:\[feat[^][]+]|\(feat[^()]+\))', '', st))
```

Output:

```
Skank Up (Oh Lawd)
Skank Up (Oh Lawd)
Skank Up (Oh Lawd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this using the one-liner [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) command:

```
re.sub(r" \[feat[^\]]*\]", "", st)
```

Which transforms your input like this:

```
Skank Up [feat. Ding Dong] (Oh Lawd)  
Skank Up (Oh Lawd)
```

---

You can modify it to accept different types of brackets too, such as `(` and `[`:

```
re.sub(r" [\[\(]feat[^\])]*[)\]]", "", st)
```